# Ionic 2 platform height and width inconsistency with orientation changes

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to get the screen height and width of the `platform` object, but evidently the screen orientation confuses these values.

Test code:

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
      console.log("orientation", screenOrientation.type);
      console.log("platform height", this.platform.height());
      console.log("platform width", this.platform.width());

      events.subscribe('orientation-changed', (screenOrientation) => {
        console.log("orientation", screenOrientation.type);
        console.log("platform height", this.platform.height());
        console.log("platform width", this.platform.width());
      });
    });
```

I run the app starting in portrait mode, and I get:

```
orientation portrait-primary
platform height 567
platform width 360
```

I rotate the phone to landscape, and I get:

```
orientation landscape-primary
platform height 567
platform width 360
```

Until now, everything seems to be in order.
**But now, if I turn the phone back to portrait mode**, I get:

```
orientation portrait-primary
platform height 335
platform width 598
```

If I turn it again to landscape:

```
orientation landscape-primary
platform height 567
platform width 360
```

How can I get the correct height and width, without being concerned about the phone orientation?

Comment: Is your second example (landscape) correct? Isn't it supposed to be h:360, w:567?

Comment: @realharry Ionic platform unfirtunately has the behavior of keeping the height and width constant in terms of orientation. So instead of updating the height and width, It updates the "definition" of height and width...
Are you experiencing something different?

Comment: No, I don't have access to any ionic app. Just trying to understand the behavior you describe. So, you are expecting h/w to be constant regardless of the orientation. (Hence, the third example is problematic, I suppose.)

Comment: its is but natural u subscribe to orientation change event the height width also changes according to your orientation ..what u want i dont really get it :( @PaulIsaris

Comment: @KishanOza thanks for your comment. If you look at the logs I provide, you will notice that when I rotate the phone at the third time, I get totally different values for width and height...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same thing. My solution was to store the platform height and width once in the component constructor then use those values in the event handler.

In the constructor:

```
    if(this._screenOrientation.type === this._screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.PORTRAIT
      || this._screenOrientation.type === this._screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.PORTRAIT_PRIMARY
      || this._screenOrientation.type === this._screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.PORTRAIT_SECONDARY){

      this._pxDeviceWidth = this._platform.width(); 
      this._pxDeviceHeight = this._platform.height(); 
    }else{
      this._pxDeviceWidth = this._platform.height();
      this._pxDeviceHeight = this._platform.width();
    }
```

Then, just reference `this._pxDeviceWidth` or `this._pxDeviceHeight` in your event handler function.